# What is best practice for filtering a map in React JSX return

Tags: reactjs

When returning the below in a component to render cards where would you put a filter on something like this?

```
    {state.messages.map((message, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <Center>
            <Box
                maxW={'850px'}
                w={'full'}
                boxShadow={'2xl'}
                rounded={'md'}
                p={6}
                overflow={'hidden'}
                >
                    <Flex>
                    <h4>UserID: {message.id}</h4>
                    <Spacer/>
                    <Button onClick={'test'} colorScheme='teal' variant='solid' >
                    <DeleteIcon/>
                    </Button>
                    </Flex>
                    <h3>User(email for now): {message.user} </h3>
                    <h2 >message: {message.message}</h2>
                    <p>Date: {message.createdAt}</p>
                </Box>
            </Center>
        <Container height={50}/>
        </div>   
        ))}
```

My first thought was something like

```
{state.messages.filter((message) => message.id).map((message, index) => (... 

this doesn't return anything but a regular map so not it probably just an example

...}
```

So hoping someone can explain what best practice is for filtering a map in returned jsx. can you even do what I'm trying to do without callstack errors?

edit: someone said the snippet is the right way, so i'll fix it in the morning and update/close this. if anyone else wants to confirm overnight too many thanks

Comment: I would say your approach is the best approach. How do you mean it doesn't return anything? Note that if message.id is `undefined` or `0` those entries will be removed.

Comment: that snippet i wrote just returns a regular old mapped card. I need to add a conditional to it anyways for auth context, i just wasn't sure if i call filter after map or before. I don't use filter often and just needed to double check and thats what looked right at first glance. thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is the best approach.

Firstly, `filter` and `map` is the clearest functions to use.

Secondly, it's better to use `filter` before `map` for two reasons:

- By removing unwanted items before mapping them, you save computations as you don't map the unwanted items.
- The map function returns `JSX.Element`s which is much harder to apply a filter on than the objects in `state.messages`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other user in the thread suggested this is solution I went with and it works great

```
{state.messages.filter((message) => message.id === user?.issuer).map((message, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <Center>
            <Box
                maxW={'850px'}
                w={'full'}
                boxShadow={'2xl'}
                rounded={'md'}
                p={6}
                overflow={'hidden'}
                >
                    <Flex>
                    <h4>UserID: {message.id}</h4>
                    <Spacer/>
                    <Button onClick={'test'} colorScheme='teal' variant='solid' >
                    <DeleteIcon/>
                    </Button>
                    </Flex>
                    <h3>User(email for now): {message.user} </h3>
                    <h2 >message: {message.message}</h2>
                    <p>Date: {message.createdAt}</p>
                </Box>
            </Center>
        <Container height={50}/>
        </div>   
        ))}
```

user?.issuer is context auth ID so it maps based on having the ID of a previous post === to your auth id